# video file name doesn't load correctly

Tags: php, video

I'm new to PHP.  Everything else works on my site okay but I seem to have an issue with this particular piece of code.  The `$efn` is my file name, and I need to retrieve it from a MySQL database but this code doesn't seem to work.  It works in a normal video container but not when using the `if` statement.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
    <?php
$video_container = substr($efn, -3);
if ($video_container == 'mp4') {
    echo '<video preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="../images/<?php echo $thumb ?>" controls="controls" autoPlay="false">
<source src="<?php echo $efn ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>';
}
else {
    echo '<video height="620" width="480" controls>
<source src="<?php echo $efn ?>" type ="video/avi" />
</video>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you provide more details on what "doesn't load correctly" means in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax problem when printing the string. Replace the `<?php echo $fn ?>` section by `' . $efn . '`

Like this:

```
$video_container = substr($efn, -3);
if ($video_container == 'mp4') {
    echo '<video preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="../images/<?php echo $thumb ?>" controls="controls" autoPlay="false">
<source src="' . urlencode($efn)  . '" type="video/mp4">
</video>';
}
else {
    echo '<video height="620" width="480" controls>
<source src="' . urlencode($efn) . '" type ="video/avi" />
</video>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick replay all works great now... apart from my avi files dont want to play but thats another issue for another time lol

Comment: hehe :) Nice to see that it helped. Maybe the file won't play because of special chars in it's name. You should try to `$efn = urlencode($efn);` before using it.

Comment: like i said im new to this so where would i put that?  

the avi problem is it says the file isnt there. :(

Comment: Check my update. But, like I said, I don't know if this will fix the problem. But it should be done anyway

Comment: for some reason if u stick the urlencode($efn); it stops the video playing altogether :(